dotenv file only read one of variable
dotenv only gets one variable and that variable is the only variable that is working. I also tried making test.env file and that file also only gets mariadb_pwd.
my .env file has the following:
MARIADB_HOST:localhost
MARIADB_USER:root
MARIADB_PWD: 1234123123123
PATH_1:./uploads/
PATH_2:./uploads_webp/

I also tried the following:
MARIADB_HOST:"localhost"
MARIADB_USER:"root"
MARIADB_PWD: "1234123123123"
PATH_1:"./uploads/"
PATH_2:"./uploads_webp/"

also replaced with " to '
it seems like it only read MARIADB_PWD. No other process.env read host pwd path etc. All of them only gives MARIADB_PWD
this is my node.js file:
require('dotenv').config({path:path.resolve(__dirname+"/.env")});
console.log(process.env.MARIADB_PWD);
console.log(process.env.PATH_1);
console.log(process.env.Path_2);

console.log(process.env)

this is my output
1234123123123
undefined
undefined
{
  SHELL: '/bin/bash',
  NVM_RC_VERSION: '',
  COLORTERM: 'truecolor',
  XDG_CONFIG_DIRS: '/etc/xdg',
  XDG_SESSION_PATH: '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0',
  XDG_MENU_PREFIX: 'lxde-pi-',
  TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: '1.94.2',
  GTK_IM_MODULE: 'ibus',
  LANGUAGE: 'ko_KR.UTF-8',
  _LXSESSION_PID: '1124',
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK: '/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXjXcoMS/agent.1124',
  XDG_CONFIG_HOME: '/home/pi/.config',
  XMODIFIERS: '@im=ibus',
  DESKTOP_SESSION: 'LXDE-pi',
  SSH_AGENT_PID: '1214',
  NO_AT_BRIDGE: '1',
  XDG_SEAT: 'seat0',
  PWD: '/home/pi/Documents/WorkSpace',
  XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP: 'LXDE-pi-x',
  LOGNAME: 'pi',
  QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME: 'qt5ct',
  XDG_SESSION_TYPE: 'x11',
  GPG_AGENT_INFO: '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1',
  XAUTHORITY: '/home/pi/.Xauthority',
  VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE: '/usr/share/code/code',
  XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR: '/var/lib/lightdm/data/pi',
  HOME: '/home/pi',
  LANG: 'ko_KR.UTF-8',
  LS_COLORS: 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=00:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.avif=01;35:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:*~=00;90:*#=00;90:*.bak=00;90:*.old=00;90:*.orig=00;90:*.part=00;90:*.rej=00;90:*.swp=00;90:*.tmp=00;90:*.dpkg-dist=00;90:*.dpkg-old=00;90:*.ucf-dist=00;90:*.ucf-new=00;90:*.ucf-old=00;90:*.rpmnew=00;90:*.rpmorig=00;90:*.rpmsave=00;90:',
  XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: 'LXDE',
  GIT_ASKPASS: '/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh',
  XDG_SEAT_PATH: '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0',
  CHROME_DESKTOP: 'code-url-handler.desktop',
  CLUTTER_IM_MODULE: 'ibus',
  NVM_DIR: '/home/pi/.config/nvm',
  VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS: '',
  XDG_SESSION_CLASS: 'user',
  TERM: 'xterm-256color',
  USER: 'pi',
  VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE: '/run/user/1000/vscode-git-77d79c99de.sock',
  DISPLAY: ':0',
  SHLVL: '1',
  NVM_CD_FLAGS: '',
  QT_IM_MODULE: 'ibus',
  XDG_VTNR: '7',
  XDG_SESSION_ID: '1',
  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: '/run/user/1000',
  LC_ALL: 'ko_KR.UTF-8',
  VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN: '/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js',
  XDG_DATA_DIRS: '/usr/local/share:/usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides:/usr/share:/usr/share/gdm:/var/lib/menu-xdg:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop',
  GDK_BACKEND: 'x11',
  PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin',
  GDMSESSION: 'LXDE-pi-x',
  SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN: 'gtk3',
  ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: 'LXDE',
  DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus',
  TERM_PROGRAM: 'vscode',
  TEXTDOMAIN: 'Linux-PAM',
  _: '/usr/bin/node',
  MARIADB_PWD: '1234123123123',
  VIPSHOME: '/target'
}

I am only getting expected output for mariadb_pwd for some reason.
i am using vscode on rasberry pi 5.
also creasted test.env file same value in .env file which also only gives mariadb_pwd value
IT WAS WORKING FINE THREE DAYS AGO AND ALL OF SUDDEN IT'S NOT WORKING AT ALL

If you guys are wondering if changed value of mariadb_pwd. I already have. it gave me changed value

I don't know exacly why it's working, but I believe the correct syntax might use = instead of :. In an .env file, the proper format is to use = without spaces around it to assign environment variables.

I'm not sure how its working for even one with a colon, I wouldn't expect it to either.

Thank you so much it fixed the problem. Still doesn't know why it was working three days ago and for some reason  and MARADB_PWD still works. I really don't get it
